# Tan spots and curling leaves on tomato plants: sun damage?

Tags: watering, tomatoes, damage

My tomato plant leaves have tan spots and curling which progresses and impacts the whole leaf over a couple days.  The leaves higher up are most affected.

We had a few cold days recently - around 40 degrees fahrenheit at night.  I don't see any bugs, and the plants were healthy a week ago.  I haven't introduced any new plants or soil, and they're inside a closed greenhouse.  They get watered once a day early in the morning with about 0.1 to 0.2 inches of water.

Will the plants recover?  Would a different watering schedule help?

Thanks!

[image: tomato plant leaves with tan spots and curling]

Comment: Update: I added fertilizer and increased watering - the plants were much happier after.